# How can I browse to my new hosting site using browser?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, redirects

Hi I have a new hosting site and my domain is still redirecting to my old domain.I have now my shared IP address and ftp details.
How can I browse my new hosting site using
`http://ipaddress/foldername` (ex:`http://192.255.255.0`)
So I can test if my scipt is running?

Comment: Who's the hosting company?

Answer (score 4):

Usually new domain DNS settings propagate within 24 hours. However, if you're impatient, you can try this (steps 1 and 2 are only needed if you don't have the new server IP yet):

1. Find a DNS lookup tool (such as [kloth.net](http://www.kloth.net/services/nslookup.php)) which lets you perform DNS lookups using specific name servers.
2. Enter your new web host's name servers and your domain name and perform a lookup.
3. Open your hosts file (in windows, it's `%SystemDirectory%\drivers\etc\hosts`, which is usually `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`; on *nix it's `/etc/hosts`) and enter an entry for the domain that points to the IP retrieved earlier and save.

Your Hosts file entry should look something like this:

```
192.168.1.1        example.com
```

This should allow you to access your domain on your new host. However, I recommend removing these entries after the DNS has propagated, as your web server IP may change in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If it's shared hosting, and you haven't also purchased a dedicated IP(if offered), the IP address probably won't be helpful.

Some hosts do set up a usable temporary address of some sort, often as a sub-domain of theirs, but without knowing which host, there's no telling what that would be.

Comment: Some also allow you to access the account via `userdir`, using a tidle and the server hostname. E.g. `server3.megahost.com/~fred/` or even `4.2.2.3/~fred` would get you to the document root for the user `fred`. Many these days disable that feature for additional security since it does let someone from the outside 'guess' at valid system user names.